# Form Control from external vb executable

Tags: vb.net

Working in Visual Studio 2015

I have a form, and I want a section of the form to be a placeholder, which is filled by another executable during run-time.  That way I can just create a new executable specific for a certain usage without having to recompile and redistribute the main program.  Is this possible?

Comment: which type of data is used to fill that section? some string, or image or tabular data...?

Comment: Buttons, text boxes, combo-boxes.  It would hopefully just look like another part of the form, just modular.

Comment: _Why_? You can use MDI if that's what you're after.

Comment: It sort of sounds like a harder to use UserControl to me